# How to full fill Location() by your own value?

Tags: android, kotlin, location

I couldnt understand how to fill something like this by my own values without gps connection:

```
val lastLocation: Location? = Location()
```

When we input provider like this:

```
val lastLocation: Location? = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
```

lastLocation values are null.

On the one hand Location() has its own constructor(as I understand) and even method set(), but l I can't figure out how to fill it with my own values.

---

Maybe someone can show an example or provide a useful link?

Comment: You'd need to call the set functions to set all of the data you care about.  The constructor won't take  the values.  So each piece of data you want to set, you'll have to call the setter on.

Comment: It sounds like an answer on my question! And as I understand it's imposible to set up all values at once, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the most convenient way in order to fill your data, that I have found:

```
  lastLocation: Location? = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).apply {
        latitude = 56.491232323
        longitude = 84.973284721
        speed = 12.2f
        altitude = 86.4
        accuracy = 11.1f
        bearing = 90.0f
        bearingAccuracyDegrees = 1.42f
    }
```